# NGINX resolving a non configured domain, why?

Tags: nginx, server, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy, winginx

I have one server running on: http://localhost:8080

I'm configuring a sample `NGINX` server.

I copied from internet the following configuration:

```
# user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  logs/error.log;
error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
error_log  logs/error.log  info;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile            on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    # gzip              on;

    server
    {
        listen 80;
        server_name mydomain01.com www.mydomain01.com;

        location /
        {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
            include "../proxy_params.conf";
        }
    }

}
```

On the hosts file I have just the following entries:

```
127.0.0.1 mydomain01.com
127.0.0.1 www.mydomain01.com;
127.0.0.1 mydomain02.com
127.0.0.1 www.mydomain02.com;
```

When I go to: http://mydomain01.com I get the same content as on: http://localhost:8080

**My question is:**

Why when I go to: http://mydomain02.com I also get the same content as on: http://localhost:8080?

I think I should not get that content because this last domain is not on the `NGINX` configuration.

Do I have an error on the configuration above?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nginx` **always** contains a *default server* which will handle requests for server names that do not match a `server_name` directive. If you do not define a `default_server`, `nginx` will use the first `server` block with a matching `location`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#miscellaneous_names) for details.